# Angular 2: Is there an eventaggregator?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, eventaggregator

I need a central, singleton Angular 2 event aggregator for cross component/module communication.

**Is there an event aggregator for Angular 2 (7.3.6), that is "ready-to-go" and which can be installed with npm?**

I have seen few custom implementations, but I could not find any "official" or "widely accepted" node module for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There two types of implementations that I know of and have used in projects. Depending on your requirements, both may fit your request:

#### NGX Message Bus

A basic "bus" style lib, enables exchanging messages / events between components or among the whole of your application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-message-bus

#### Redux based communication / state management

Depending on the scale of your application (read: if it's rather big), you may be interested in Redux-style libraries like [NGRX](https://ngrx.io/), [NGXS](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/) or [Akita](https://github.com/datorama/akita). Strictly speaking, these libs are not purely messaging systems, but state management projects. Redux has a lot of advantages (immutable state, traceable actions and state changes) but usually also comes with a learning curve.

Comment: Sure, let me know what solution worked for you in the end

Comment: I have to figure it out. I'll let you know here in the comments later.

Comment: I promised to come back and let you, what solution I have chosen and the answer is: None of the above. The leanest one, NGX Message Bus, was still not lean enough for my purpose. Based on an example, that I found, I have chosen to write my own implemenation. The example can be found here: [link](http://abusanad.net/2016/08/20/angular-2-cross-modules-communication-eventaggregator/) Anyway, your above suggestions were excellent.

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting me know.